# Defining the limits of a ggplot2 square in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this picture: [image]

As you can see, xlim (0, 2) and ylim(0,2) range from 0.0 to 2.0.

However, there are four extra areas present beyond these limits, as shown in red here:
[image]

How can I remove this area, and make the exact bottom left corner of the square to be (0.0, 0.0) and the top right corner to be (2.0, 2.0), so that this reddish are is removed?

Comment: `+ coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE)`